# Synchronous Angular 8 HTTP request from a service

Tags: angular, rest, http, d3.js, service

I'm trying to consume an http GET request from an Angular 8 service. I need to load some data via the RESTful service and then use them in order to fill a D3 graph (D3 side isn't the problem).

I'm trying to use the async/await function.

In the ngOnInit I try to load data with the HTTP request like, this:

```
ngOnInit() { 
  console.log("ngOnInit");
  this.loadRESTDataSync();
}

async loadRESTDataSync() {    
  console.log("PRE-REST!")
  this.m_graph = await this.loadRESTDataPromise(); 
  console.log("POST-REST!");
  //works on m_graph...
}

private loadRESTDataPromise(): Promise<any> {
    return this.service.getData().toPromise()
      .then(resp => resp as MyObjects[]);
}
```

Then I try to create the D3 chart inside the ngAfterViewInit, like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
  this.createChart();
}
```

The sequence of console print is:

```
ngOnInit
PRE_REST!
ngAfterViewInit
POST-REST!
```

So, when I run the app, the chart is empty because the ngAfterViewInit is called BEFORE the http rest call termination (so there aren't yet data to display).

The ngAfterViewInit should be called AFTER the loadRestDataSync/loadRESTDataPromise termination.

Which is the correct way to do this? Maybe I'm in wrong about the cycle hook?

I have the onResize method implemented and the graph is correct if I resize the window, but the problem is the first load.

Can you suggest to me some correct way?

Many thanks, bye.

Answer (score 0):

`loadRESTDataSync()` is async so it dose not block the ui thread so `ngAfterViewInit()` is free to be happened. it is wise to not block the ui thread for data fetch as you noticed. now all you need is to call `createChart()` after `this.m_graph = await this.loadRESTDataPromise();`.

I had same issue and in may scenario, i preferred to raise a 'fetch complete message' and react to this event:

```
dataIsLoaded = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {
     this.dataIsLoaded.subscribe(d => this.createChart(d));
     this.loadRESTDataSync();
}

async loadRESTDataSync() {    
  this.m_graph = await this.loadRESTDataPromise();
  //works on m_graph...
  this.dataIsLoaded.next(d);
}

this.createChart(data) {
  //
}
```

you can just store data in a variable and when your data is ready just raise an empty message to notify subscribed methods.